# How to store a set of values from another table in a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, set

I'm running on a version of MySQL that does not support foreign key relationships.

Suppose I have two tables, one holds a number of users while the other one holds a number of topics. I want each of the topics to have a field which holds a set of user id's who participated in that topic. I read the type SET's documentation and it says it must be values from predefined values. So how should I go about doing this?

Comment: "I'm running on a version of MySQL that does not support relationships."  -- this does not make any sense at all.

Comment: Some free server providers do not allow relationships in MySQL databases they provide. There might be unclear phrasing in my question but the end result is the same: I can't use relationships. Please don't randomly downvote when you haven't understand what's being said.

Comment: That may be the case, but you need to explain what service provider you are dealing with and what exactly they do and don't allow. Nobody is going to understand why MySQL, a relational database, would have some sort of version that does not support relationships. That literally isn't a relational database, which literally means it isn't MySQL.  This question does not make sense.

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: And I removed my down vote.

Comment: It sounds like the provider does not support MySQL engines with foreign key constraints, such as InnoDB. Instead, they just allow looser engines like MyISAM? If it is the case, it's certainly rather an odd decision.

Comment: Ahh yea, I see the edit. Very weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want an extra field, this is a very inefficient way of storing such things. You want a new table.

In your third table (called, say, `topicUsers`). you would have just two fields: `userId` and `topicId`. Then you can look at this table and `join` data from the others as needed.

This is called [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)